# Deleting multiple name-sharing folders with one command

Tags: delete

I want to delete one hidden folder from multiple locations at the same time using a single command.

It's located on multiple locations (about 100).

Is there any command which helps to delete this fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `find` for your purpose. See [`man find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/find.1.html) for more.

Say you have a directory 'mydir' in which there are several directory and sub-directory that contain a hidden folder, say '.src'. Also the directory 'mydir' itself has '.src' directory.

```
mydir
├── a
│   └── .src
├── b
│   ├── j
│   │   └── .src
│   ├── k
│   │   └── .src
│   └── .src
├── c
│   └── .src
├── d
│   └── .src
├── e
│   └── .src
└── .src
```

To remove all these folders name `.src` open a terminal and go to 'mydir' and use tha following command,

```
find . -iname '.src' -type d -exec rm -r {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks its working...really appreciate your immediate reponse